# append a value to optgroup

Tags: javascript

How do I append a value to an optgroup in an html select dynamically? Thanks.

```
            if (item.position == '/' + (currentPosition) + '/') {
                $("#parentAgency").append(
                $("<optgroup></optgroup>")
                    .val(item.level)
                );
                $("#parentAgency").append(
                    $("<option></option>")
                    .text(item.name)
                    .val(item.id)
                );
                currentPosition += 1;
            }
```

Comment: jsfiddle will be good , and what is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: I am not able to append a value to the label in the optgroup

Answer (score 0):

Create the `optgroup` element:

```
 var group = $("<optgroup />");
```

Create your `options` and `append` to the `optgroup`

```
 var option = $("<option />") //set the text and so on
```

Append:

```
 group.append(option);
```

And then append the `optgroup` to your `select`

```
$("#parentAgency").append(group);
```

Comment: so would i say something like this       $("#parentAgency").append(group = item.name)?

Comment: @jpavlov -- no - you would set the `option`'s text when you're creating the option element.

Comment: I am really lost, i would like to append the <optgroup> which is my group variable. How would i write that to append the label of the optgroup with item.name?